# How to solve this ODE? $\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2 \frac{dR}{dr}\right)=l(l+1)R$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this equation in Introduction to electrodynamics by Griffiths. The solution is given as
$R(r)=Ar^l + \frac{B}{r^{l+1}}$, where $A$ and $B$ are the arbitrary constants of the second order DE. I know The reduction method where one of the solution is to be known. What was procedure used here?

Comment: It's Cauchy-Euler 's differential equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Answer (score 0):

This admits monomial solutions since if $R(r) = r^{\lambda}$, $R'(r) = \lambda r^{\lambda-1}$ and so $r^2R'(r) = \lambda r^{\lambda+1}$. Finally, $\frac{d}{dr}(r^2 R'(r)) = \lambda(\lambda+1)r^{\lambda}$. In more abstract terms, the operator $\frac{d}{dr}r^2\frac{d}{dr}$ leaves the monomial order unchanged. $\frac{d}{dr}$ drops the monomial order by one, $r^2$ raises it by two to a net of one, and $\frac{d}{dr}$ lowers it again back to the original order.

Comment: can you elaborate on how they arrived at that specific solution with two constants?

Comment: Try solving $\lambda(\lambda+1) r^{\lambda} = l(l+1)r^{\lambda}$ for $\lambda$ in terms of $l$.

Comment: oh!!i got $\lambda=l$ and $\lambda =-(l+1)$ . i am lost, what is that equation?

Comment: That then tells you that the solutions are of the form $r^l$ and $r^{-(l+1)} = \dfrac{1}{r^{l+1}}$. Of course since this is a linear, homogeneous differential equation, a constant multiplying the solution is again a solution as well as linear combinations of solutions, so the general solution set is $$ R(r) = A r^l + B r^{-l-1}$$ which agree exactly with your solutions.